# how to copy chrome console variable value to current page script variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have an variable in chrome browser console. I want to copy the values to current page script variable.

Typing the below code in console
var myValue=2500;

I want to copy this myValue to my current page's script variable. like below.
var pageScriptVariable=myValue;

Please help me to achieve this

Comment: put a break point in the code, change the variable.

Answer (score 2):

***If*** you have the script paused in the debugger, on a line where `pageScriptVariable` is in scope, you can literally just do exactly what you have in your question in the console:

```
pageScriptVariable = myValue;
```

Then when you continue the script, it will continue using the variable's updated value.

Step by step (in Chrome's dev tools):

Setting the breakpoint by clicking next to the line we want to stop on:

[image]

Shows the output of the line before, which has the original value:

[image]

Updating the value in the console:

[image]

Switching back to the debugger ("Sources") so we can tell the script to continue:

[image]

The updated value is output:

[image]